# Getting error while Upgrading java webservice code from java 1.4 to java 1.7

Tags: java, web-services, enums, axis

We have a  websercie code written in java version 1.4 and axis 1.4
now we are  trying to upgrade to java 1.7 I am getting below errors while compiling with java 1.7 version.

[javac]
                                   ^
    [javac]   (use -source 5 or higher to use 'enum' as a keyword)

```
[javac] C:\xxx\adapter\xyz\src\abc\java\com\a\b\c\d\schema\e
```

_PrototypeSoapStub.java:30: warning: as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and
 m

ay not be used as an identifier

```
[javac]         oper.setUse(org.apache.axis.enum.Use.ENCODED);

[javac]                                     ^
[javac]   (use -source 5 or higher to use 'enum' as a keyword)
[javac] C:\xxx\adapter\xyz\src\abc\java\com\a\b\c\d\schema\e
```

_PrototypeSoapStub.java:41: warning: as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and m
ay not be used as an identifier

```
[javac]         oper.setStyle(org.apache.axis.enum.Style.RPC);

[javac]                                       ^
[javac]   (use -source 5 or higher to use 'enum' as a keyword)

[javac] C:\xxx\adapter\xyz\src\abc\java\com\a\b\c\d\schema\e
```

_PrototypeSoapStub.java:42: warning: as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and 
m

ay not be used as an identifier

```
[javac]         oper.setUse(org.apache.axis.enum.Use.ENCODED);
```

could you please suggest how to resolve this??

Answer (score 1):

Java 5 added a language feature calls enums.

**From Java 5 enum cannot be used as an identifier (method name, variable name, part of package) as it is a keyword.**

**You have to use newer version of the library.**

Comment: While true, this answer isn't really all that helpful if the keyword is being used by a third-party library, as is the case for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Javadocs for apache axis 1.4](https://axis.apache.org/axis/java/apiDocs/org/apache/axis/enum/Use.html), you'll see that `org.apache.axis.enum.Use` is deprecated.  You should change all of your references to use `org.apache.axis.constants.Scope` instead.  This will get you around using the `enum` keyword as an identifier, which, as you've discovered, you can't do anymore.

As a side note, Axis 1.4 hasn't had an update in almost a decade.  It's probably time to start investigating rewriting this in something that's still maintained and part of the standard.  Java EE has an [integrated web service framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html) that's generally easier to use than Axis, and still actively maintained.  However, it would represent a major re-write, so that may not be an immediate option for you.